# Update values on one table from another table when criteria is met

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to update one table in my db depending on a value from another table.
The 2 tables are:

```
 QUOTES(
   QUOTE_ID,
   APPROVAL
 )

PRODUCTS(
  QUOTE_ID_FK,
  LINE_APPROVAL
)
```

I need to update all `PRODUCTS.LINE_APPROVAL` to `'Y'` where the `QUOTES.APPROVAL = 'Y'`

I have tried something like this but fails as I don't have the syntax quite right but hopefully you can see what I'm trying to achieve:

```
UPDATE 
    PRODUCTS
SET 
    LINE_APPROVAL = 'Y'
FROM
    QUOTES,
    PRODUCTS            
WHERE
    PRODUCTS.QUOTE_ID = QUOTES.QUOTE_ID_FK
AND
    QUOTES.APPROVAL = 'Y'
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this query will, update all products which have a value in `PQUOTE_ID` that appears in the quotes table column `Quote_ID_FK` (and approval is Y).

```
UPDATE 
    PRODUCTS
SET 
    LINE_APPROVAL = 'Y'
WHERE 
    PQUOTE_ID IN 
       (SELECT
           QUOTE_ID_FK 
        FROM
           QUOTES
        WHERE
           APPROVAL = 'Y')
```

Answer (score 3):

The @joelharkes answer with the `WHERE ... IN` will work if you adjust the ID column names. You can also use [MERGE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_9016.htm):

```
MERGE INTO Products
USING (
  SELECT Quote_ID FROM Quotes
  WHERE Approval = 'Y') QtApp
ON (Products.Quote_ID_FK = QtApp.Quote_ID)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET Line_Approval = 'Y'
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i wasnt aware of MERGE.

Comment: @Ed - why the sub query ? you can add a `where` to the update clause.

Comment: @haki - You have to match `Products` rows against a set of data, and you get the set from a subquery: `USING (SELECT ...) QtApp`. It's a required part of the `MERGE` syntax. The `ON` clause specifies how you match `PRODUCTS` to the set from the subquery. You can put a `WHERE` in the `UPDATE` for additional filtering but it can't be used to match rows. Remember, Oracle won't let you update using a joined query like SQL Server will, which is why the answers from Harshil and Codesleuth, while excellent, weren't accepted here - they work for SQL Server but not for Oracle.

Comment: @Ed for the sake of education. assuming that {quote_id} is unique -  this will not work ? `merge into products
using quotes q
on (products.quote_id_fk = q.quote_id)
when matched then
update set line_approval = 'y'
where q.approval = 'y'`

Comment: @haki - I see what you mean now :) I'm pretty sure your version would work. I normally try to make the initial set (from `USING...`) as small as possible, hence the filtering there. Because your version potentially has to do more matches against the `PRODUCTS` table (and still has to filter on `Quotes.Approval`) it *may* be slower, but that's just a guess. Either way yours is definitely easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

You have your column names in the wrong place. Your query should be:

```
UPDATE  PRODUCTS
SET     LINE_APPROVAL = 'Y'
FROM    QUOTES, PRODUCTS            
WHERE   PRODUCTS.QUOTE_ID_FK = QUOTES.QUOTE_ID
AND     QUOTES.APPROVAL = 'Y'
```

Or `INNER JOIN`:

```
UPDATE  PRODUCTS
SET     LINE_APPROVAL = 'Y'
FROM    PRODUCTS
        INNER JOIN QUOTES ON PRODUCTS.QUOTE_ID_FK = QUOTES.QUOTE_ID
WHERE   QUOTES.APPROVAL = 'Y'
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  UPDATE PRODUCTS
    SET  LINE_APPROVAL = 'Y'
    FROM PRODUCTS
    INNER JOIN QUOTES ON PQUOTE_ID = QUOTE_ID_FK
    WHERE  APPROVAL = 'Y'
```

Ya

```
UPDATE  PRODUCTS 
SET LINE_APPROVAL = 'Y'
WHERE PQUOTE_ID IN 
(SELECT QUOTE_ID_FK  FROM
QUOTES WHERE APPROVAL = 'Y')
```