# How can I trigger an update to a value in a table when criteria is met on a different table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Aware there is an almost identical question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16168253/update-values-on-one-table-from-another-table-when-criteria-is-met), but that covers the SQL query required, rather than the mechanism of event triggering.

Lets say I have two tables. One table contains performance data for each staff member each week. The other table is a table that holds the staff members information. What I want is to update a value in the table to a Y or N based on whether that staff member left at the week date.

**staffTable**

```
+----------+----------------+------------+
| staff_id |   staff_name   | leave_date |
+----------+----------------+------------+
|        1 | Joseph Blogges | 2020-01-24 |
|        2 | Joe Bloggs     | 9999-12-31 |
|        3 | Joey Blogz     | 9999-12-31 |
+----------+----------------+------------+
```

**targetTable**

```
+------------+----------+--------+-----------+
| week_start | staff_id | target | left_flag |
+------------+----------+--------+-----------+
| 2020-01-13 |        1 |     10 | N         |
| 2020-01-20 |        1 |     10 | N         |
| 2020-01-27 |        1 |      8 | Y         |
+------------+----------+--------+-----------+
```

What I am trying to do is have the `left_flag` automatically change from 'N' to 'Y' when the `week_start` value is *greater* than `leave_date` of the staff member (in the other table).

I have tried successfully putting this into a view, which works, but the problem is that existing applications, views and queries will need to all reference a new view instead of a table and I want to be able to query the data table as my front-end has issues interacting in live with a view instead of a table.

I have also successfully used a UDF to return the `leave_date` and then create computed column that will check if this UDF variable is greater than the `start_date` column and this worked fine until I realised that the UDF is the most resource consuming query on the entire server and is completely disproportionate.

Is there a way that I can trigger an update to the staffTable when a criteria is met in another table, or is there a totally better and different way of doing this? If it can't be done easily, I'll try to switch to a view and work around it in the front-end.

Comment: The clean and safe way is the view.

Comment: Do you not want to get this at the source? What populates `targetTable`? Would it not be cleaner to have that set the flag, based on if the employee has left?

Comment: I realise it looks that way in this simplistic example @Leonidas199x, but the data in the `targetTable` is populated up to 8 weeks into the future. So when it comes to maintaining the record in the current week, the administrator needs the data "removed" to ignore the leaver, but we need to retain it in the table for record keeping. So essentially, we can't capture at source as it may not be known that the staff member has left yet when it's populated and may occur after the event.

Comment: @RazorKillBen I may be confused, it is Friday afternoon, but, how would a trigger solve this any differently than at the source? If you have data in the future in `targetTable`, then you want an insertion of a `leave_date` in the `staffTable` table to update the `leave_flag` where the `week_start` is after the leave date. I would have thought it better to have this logic in your application, as opposed to hidden in a trigger. Triggers can be a pain... but that said, I don't know all the detail, it is just my opinion, for what it is worth.

Comment: @Leonidas199x I would agree with you in all aspects of the logic; it just doesn't apply to this situation I think. The user will 'save' their team target data 6 weeks in the future (expecting John A to still be here in 6 weeks). John A leaves the organisation, and so when the 6 weeks time makes it to the current week and they need to then 'submit' the final copy of that weeks data, they'll be retrieving information for John A who has left, and doesn't need to be submitted. I want the `leave_flag` to be populated so the `WHERE` clause can be set to `leave_flag = 'FALSE'` if that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to describe the process rather than writing the code.

What you are describing can be accomplished using triggers on `staffTable`.  When a new row is *inserted* or *updated* the trigger would change any rows in `targetTable`.  This would be an after insert/update trigger.

The heart of the trigger would be:

```
update tt
    set left_flag = 'Y'
    from targettable tt join
         inserted i 
         on tt.staff_id = i.staff_id 
    where i.leave_date < tt.week_start and
          tt.left_flag <> 'Y';
```

Comment: Thanks @GordonLinoff - this is exactly what I was hoping for; some sort of "event" I can attach a process to. Can the trigger be set to a criteria? The leaver isn't removed from the table for record keeping and keying purposes, so can we have it that if the `leave_date` is amended it then fires that code to essentially `UPDATE` anything that the `WHERE` clause catches?

Comment: Yes, look into `inserted` & `deleted` tables that are available to you in triggers. You will want to compare the leave date from the updated to what is there, so you only update when the date has changed, not when a general update is done to a record. Which opens the question of, how do you undo this if the wrong date is entered? May want to cater for that logic, too

Comment: @Leonidas199x that's a fantastic point about `deleted` triggers; definitely food for thought. In this case it wouldn't be an issue as the update would change a deleted flag to "Y", so if it was then changed back it would go back as a "N". But this is generally a great observation that I know I've overlooked in another project, so thank you!